# scraping <script> content with requests_html prints out type attribute

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, python-requests-html

The website has the needed content inside a script tag like that:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id": "https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/888455/philips-65oled706-ambilight-2021.html",
    "name": "Philips 65OLED706 - Ambilight (2021)",
    "image": "https://image.coolblue.de/422x390/products/1612792",
    "url": "https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/888455/philips-65oled706-ambilight-2021.html",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Philips"
    },
    "description": "Mit dem Philips 650LED706 - Ambilight (2021) genießt du lebensechte Bilder. Dieser Fernseher ist mit einem 4K OLED-Bildschirm ausgestattet, wodurch Millionen von Pixeln einzeln Farben erzeugen, aufleuchten oder sich selbst ganz ausschalten. Dadurch siehst du Bilder mit einem starken Kontrast, jedes Detail in Schatten und schwarze Bilder sind wirklich schwarz. So hebt sich beispielsweise der Mond klar von einem dunklen Sternenhimmel ab. Der Fernseher unterstützt denk dem 10-Bit-Display gleichzeitig über eine Milliarde Farben. Dadurch kommen HDR-Bilder gut zur Geltung und feine Farbunterschiede sind deutlich sichtbar, sowie beispielsweise alle Orangetöne bei einem Sonnenuntergang. Dank der Bildwiederholfrequenz von 100 Hertz und einem intelligenten P5 Gen5 Prozessor sind schnelle Bilder auch besonders flüssig. So hast du nie Probleme mit Bildrucklern bei der Formel 1 oder einem spannenden Actionfilm. Zudem verbessert dieser Prozessor Bilder einer geringeren Quelle wie beispielsweise Full HD-Inhalte. Suchst du einen Fernseher, der mehr leistet als nur die Anzeige von Bildern? Kleine Lampen an der Rückseite des Fernsehers beleuchten die Wand in den Farben vom Bild. Dieses besondere TV-Erlebnis sorgt dafür, dass du deine Lieblingsinhalte noch intensiver erlebst.",    "sku": "888455",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "1999",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition"
            },
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "worstRating": "1",
            "bestRating": "10",
            "ratingValue": "9.6",
            "reviewCount": "1"
        }
    }
</script>
```

I need to get out the "description": and the "brand" "name".
with my code i want to scrape the inside of the script tag:

```
    description = r.html.find('script')[13]
    print(r.html.find('script')[13])
```

however, the output isnt the actual json data but only the type attribute, like that: https://prnt.sc/1ugjtr5

what can i do to get the actual inside data, description and brand name?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we'd do it with javascript.

```js
let x = document.querySelector("script[type='application/ld+json']")
let obj = JSON.parse(x.textContent)

console.log(obj.description)
```

```html
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "@id": "https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/888455/philips-65oled706-ambilight-2021.html",
    "name": "Philips 65OLED706 - Ambilight (2021)",
    "image": "https://image.coolblue.de/422x390/products/1612792",
    "url": "https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/888455/philips-65oled706-ambilight-2021.html",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Philips"
    },
    "description": "Mit dem Philips 650LED706 - Ambilight (2021) genießt du lebensechte Bilder. Dieser Fernseher ist mit einem 4K OLED-Bildschirm ausgestattet, wodurch Millionen von Pixeln einzeln Farben erzeugen, aufleuchten oder sich selbst ganz ausschalten. Dadurch siehst du Bilder mit einem starken Kontrast, jedes Detail in Schatten und schwarze Bilder sind wirklich schwarz. So hebt sich beispielsweise der Mond klar von einem dunklen Sternenhimmel ab. Der Fernseher unterstützt denk dem 10-Bit-Display gleichzeitig über eine Milliarde Farben. Dadurch kommen HDR-Bilder gut zur Geltung und feine Farbunterschiede sind deutlich sichtbar, sowie beispielsweise alle Orangetöne bei einem Sonnenuntergang. Dank der Bildwiederholfrequenz von 100 Hertz und einem intelligenten P5 Gen5 Prozessor sind schnelle Bilder auch besonders flüssig. So hast du nie Probleme mit Bildrucklern bei der Formel 1 oder einem spannenden Actionfilm. Zudem verbessert dieser Prozessor Bilder einer geringeren Quelle wie beispielsweise Full HD-Inhalte. Suchst du einen Fernseher, der mehr leistet als nur die Anzeige von Bildern? Kleine Lampen an der Rückseite des Fernsehers beleuchten die Wand in den Farben vom Bild. Dieses besondere TV-Erlebnis sorgt dafür, dass du deine Lieblingsinhalte noch intensiver erlebst.",    "sku": "888455",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "1999",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition"
            },
        "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "worstRating": "1",
            "bestRating": "10",
            "ratingValue": "9.6",
            "reviewCount": "1"
        }
    }
</script>
```